# automatically instantiating objects

Tags: python, class, oop, instantiation

```
players_list = [Ani, Paty, Felix, Alex]

class Player:

def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.score = 0
    self.vote = 0
    self.player_hand = []
    self.choice = ''
    self.player_hand = []
            
def player_turn(self):
    print(self.name, "'s turn")


def p_vote(self):
    print(self.name, " voted")
```

I tried to iterate over the list, but it always gives me an error: `NameError: name 'Ani' is not defined`

```
for player in players_list:
    player = Player(str(player))
```

But doing all the process manually work:

`Ani = Player("Ani")`, etc

Is there any way that i can automate this process?

Comment: Why have you used quotes in the example that works, and not in the one that doesn't?

Comment: for obj in players_list: object(obj) = Player(obj)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the thing you should know, the `players_list` that you have declared are not containing strings, they are being considered as variables which you have not defined anywhere, and therefore the `NameError`.

Now, if you want to correct this, and if you actually intend to store objects of Player in `players_list`, then you can do the following:

```
players_list = ["Ani", "Paty", "Felix", "Alex"]

class Player:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.score = 0
        self.vote = 0
        self.player_hand = []
        self.choice = ''
        self.player_hand = []
            
    def player_turn(self):
        print(self.name, "'s turn")
    
    
    def p_vote(self):
        print(self.name, " voted")
        
for i in range(len(players_list)):
    players_list[i]=Player(players_list[i])
```

This will store Player objects in the list you have declared just the thing that you expect to get.

Answer (score 0):

You are having problems with the players not being defined. So `players_list = [Ani, Paty, Felix, Alex]` will throw an error because the objects `Ani`, `Paty`, `Felizx`, and `Alex` do not exist.

```
 class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.score = 0
        self.vote = 0
        self.player_hand = []
        self.choice = ''
        self.player_hand = []
            
    def player_turn(self):
        print(self.name, "'s turn")


    def p_vote(self):
        print(self.name, " voted")
```

Now, we need to iterate through the list.

```
players_list = ['Ani', 'Paty', 'Felix', 'Alex']
players = [Player(player) for player in players_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to dynamically create variables - write code that writes code.

You could try to use the `exec` built-in function.

```
players = ['Ani', 'Paty', 'Felix', 'Alex']

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def p_vote(self):
        print(self.name + " voted.")

for player in players:
    exec( "%s = Player( '%s' )" %(player, player) )

Ani.p_vote()
```

Although, general internet advice has two points to make:

- Be cautious where you use `exec`.
- The Pythonic way is to write out the variables, "explicit is better than implicit."